# Auto insert import statement in the formate of ESM in VSCode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am coding some Node.js code and I've install @types/node for code completion. When I use a function in a Node.js built-in module, it auto insert the import statement in CommonJS, which isn't what I want. How to change this import statement in the format of ESM?
[image]